# How to select the Version of OpenCL device?

Tags: opencl

I have a little doubt about my OpenCL's Version. As the properties show in VS:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMcEA.png)

Is the OpenCL version 2.0 selected automatically, or we still have to do something to select one of the version (like 1.2 of 2.0) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of the OpenCL 2.0 runtime APIs will be available if your device supports OpenCL 2.0, but if you want to use OpenCL 2.0 features inside your kernels you will need to explicitly opt-in by passing `–cl-std=CL2.0` to `clBuildProgram()`.